# imap-send.c:865: error: storage size of 'hamc' isn't known

Tags: git, openssl, centos6

Install the git in the CentOS release 6.9 (Final).  It stop when i make and throw the exception

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please state the errors. The text on the picture is too small to read for some visitors. In addition, the text cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

The software you are compiling is not compatible with the version of OpenSSL available on your system. Your system is providing the newest version of OpenSSL (1.1.0), but the software you are compiling is expecting an earlier version of that (probably 1.0.2). OpenSSL 1.1.0 is not fully source compatible with 1.0.2. You will need to provide a version of OpenSSL 1.0.2 in addition to the system provided version and ensure your software uses that during compilation.

Comment: `/usr/local` is presumably user-supplied; CentOS 6 feature freeze was supposedly 2011, before OpenSSL 1.1.0 and even 1.0.2, and rpmfind shows it currently at 1.0.1e-57.el6 (that is, 1.0.1e plus 57 sets of backported security patches). But that doesn't change the solution.

Comment: Yes, good point.